# css are not loaded after some clicks

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile 
I have 3 pages and after some clicks between the pages the css are not rendered

LoadCss.js

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function(event) {
    $("#categoriesPage").on('pageshow', function () {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css">');
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/myCss.css">');
    });
    $("#wordPage").on('pageshow', function () {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css">');
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/myCss">');
    });
    $("#searchPage").on('pageshow', function () {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css">');
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss">');
    });
  });
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">




    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/lodash.js"></script>

    <!--player-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mainController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loadCSS.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl" ng-init="data=init()">
    <div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
               ... some logic
    </div>


    <div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
                  .. sonle logic 
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="thirdage">
             ..........

    </div>



</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I tried also to put the CSS in the header and not on on event but it still didn't work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jplayer.pink.flag.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: did you check up the inspector in browser such as Chrome? what is the error or message shown for each click and after 3 clicks?

Comment: I didn't get any error the CSS are not loaded after some times and I didn't see the image in the postion

Comment: It occurred when I moved between the different pages

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer?

Comment: Not I am using chrome

Comment: It is occurred also in Internet Explorer the problem that the image start to be big and not small and also not in the right position. The css are loaded but not affected

Comment: i think its because every time you are appending CSS without removing previously added css. Try .remove or .empty before append.

Comment: Is it a single page application?

Comment: It is 1 html file with 3 pages

Comment: Put your code directly into the HTML file and not in an external JS file, and check it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method below, using the attribute method. note the order they are applied.
This will give better compatibility for all browsers too (IE has issues):

To test, don't put your JQuery code in the external LoadCSS.js file - put it into the HTML file. It should work every time. When loading from an external JS file, some events do not always trigger when you expect due to the browser caching the file.

As @nishi says, remember to remove the old CSS before adding the new ones.

```
$('<link>')
.appendTo('head')
.attr({type : 'text/css', rel : 'stylesheet'})
.attr('href', '/styles/myfile.css');
```